# Ivy Retrieve with Classifiers

Tags: ivy

I have the following `ivy.xml`:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0"
    xmlns:maven="http://maven.apache.org">

    <configurations>
    ...
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.foo"   name="fubur"
            rev="1.3"    conf="runtime->default"/>
        <dependency org="com.snafu" name="barfu"
            rev="1.4"    conf="runtime->default">
            <artifact name="barfu" 
                maven:classifier="ID_10T" 
                type="jar" ext="jar"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

In my `build.xml`, I want to retrieve all of my jars for the war I'm building:

```
  <ivy:retrieve 
     pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[classifier]-[revision].[ext]"
     conf="runtime"/>
```

No, that won't work... There's no classifier in `fubar-1.3.jar`. It will download as `fubar--1.3.jar`

```
  <ivy:retrieve 
     pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
     conf="runtime"/>
```

That's no good either. `barfu-ID_10T-1.4.jar` will download as `barfu-1.4.jar`.

I would like the jars in my war to be included as `barfu-ID_10T-1.4.jar` and fubar-1.3-jar`. Is there an **easy** way of doing that? I know I could create two different configurations, but that is overkill. I'd rather just have the jars *miss-named* since it really doesn't affect the war itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use parentheses to specify optional components of an attribute pattern:

```
<ivy:retrieve 
     pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]"
     conf="runtime"/>
```

Comment: Did you mean _parentheses_?

Comment: @Alex I stand partially corrected thx :-) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: The english dialect would describe these as brackets.