# Multiple-artifact resolution with Ivy

Tags: eclipse, ant, dependency-management, artifactory, ivy

I need to resolve a jcuda native library via Ivy, but I'm having some trouble finding the right way to define the dependency.

I'm using Artifactory for my dependency management, and it properly identified and resolved the individual native library versions for all available plaforms (see screenshot):

[image: Artifactory screenshot]

However, I am stuck at the resolution of the

[image: Eclipse Ivy resolution error]

The error produced by Ivy shows the correct resolution path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hint in the original Maven definition for these libraries (found in my local Ivy cache, `%HOME%\.ivy2\cache\org.jcuda\jcuda-natives\windows-x86_64\ivy-0.8.0.xml.original`), which used the following classifier:

`<classifier>${jcuda.os}-${jcuda.arch}</classifier>`

In my Ivy configurations, I don't distinguish OS and architecture, but using the catenated classifier gives me `windows-x86_64`, which is the jar file I'm looking for.

I needed to add the Maven namespace (`xmlns:maven="http://maven.apache.org"`) to `ivy.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd" xmlns:maven="http://maven.apache.org">
```

And then the following dependency can use [maven:classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16344151/2074605) to resolve the specific native library I'm looking for:

```
    <dependency org="org.jcuda" name="jcuda-natives" rev="0.8.0">
        <artifact maven:classifier="windows-x86_64" ext="jar" />
    </dependency>
```